# Facebook isn't loading items shared by users on Facebook through Notifications on web

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, sharing

Basically, user Shares an item through the iOS app and can tag friends. When people comment, users are currently able to get to the Timeline story through Notifications if they are viewing it on their phone, but are NOT able to get to it via web. When clicking on the Notification on web, they are getting a “Sorry, this page isn’t available” page.

I think the link is being passed off. I'm not really sure what's going on and why users can see the Timeline story on the mobile app but not the web. Any help or insight is appreciated!